# A date-themed riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My prefix is what you might do with your date.

You and your date may use my infix as a pronoun to refer to the two of you.

You would be happy if your relationship between the two of you does my suffix.

All together, I am the last thing you would want to date. What am I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this affix-riddle uses three **homophones** rather than relying on the exact spelling of the affixes, and the answer could well be:

> **DINOSAUR**!

*My prefix is what you might do with your date.*

> You and your date might go out for a romantic meal and **DINE** in a restaurant.

*You and your date may use my infix as a pronoun to refer to the two of you.*

> Together, the two of you would describe yourselves as **US**.

*You would be happy if your relationship between the two of you does my suffix.*

> You have high hopes that your love might metaphorically **SOAR**, making you both feel like you're 'flying high'...

*All together, I am the last thing you would want to date.*

> Put it all together - **DINE-US-SOAR** - and you wouldn't want to date a **DINOSAUR**! (Old and set in their ways, or fierce and inclined to eat you...)
>
>  Unless, of course, you're a palaeontologist - then you might well like to *carbon-date* one!