# Another date-themed riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

I already posted 1 [date-themed riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109747/a-date-themed-riddle), which was solved by Stiv. Here is a second one.

My prefix might be your response if your crush asks you on a date.

You may liken your relationship to my infix when things are confusing between you.

I advise that you take my suffix if you plan on any sort of intimacy.

Altogether, if you are impressed by him/her you may use my whole word to describe your feelings toward her.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [again](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/109751/60644) we are looking at 3 affix **homophones**, which make the whole:

> **AMAZEMENT**!

*My prefix might be your response if your crush asks you on a date.*

> Without wishing to appear too keen, you might take a moment to think about your response: **UM...**

*You may liken your relationship to my infix when things are confusing between you.*

> Sometimes navigating a relationship can feel like you are finding your way in a **MAZE**.

*I advise that you take my suffix if you plan on any sort of intimacy.*

> Before leaning in for a kiss, make sure to take a **MINT** to keep your breath fresh!

*Altogether, if you are impressed by him/her you may use my whole word to describe your feelings toward her.*

> All together - **UM-MAZE-MINT** - and it sounds like you'll look into your date's eyes with a sense of **AMAZEMENT**...

Comment: u r soo close. Only ur suffix is wrong.  if you want, you can read every other letter in the following word and u can see the word i was thinking of. or you could try to figure out the correct suffix. Read every other letter in this word starting with the first letter to see the answer: ajmoadzlejmiehnpt

Comment: @YosefZaghi Okay, I think I have it now :)